# jQuery option selected half working

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form on a page which is in php.  The three functions below are called subsequently.

What I want to achieve is that the two select take the GET value and select themselves to the right value.

The orderType works fine, but the orderSel isn't. I don't know why and this is my problem.

Here's the functions :

```
function loadOrderButton()
{
  echo "<form name=\"input\" action=\"colview.php\" method=\"get\">
        <select onchange=\"this.form.submit()\" class=optionText3 name=\"orderSel\" id=\"orderSel\">
            <option class=optionText  value=\"\">ORDER BY</option>
            <option class=optionText  value=\"name\">Name</option>
            <option class=optionText  value=\"overall\">Overall</option>
            <option class=optionText  value=\"skt\">Skating</option>
            <option class=optionText  value=\"sht\">Shooting</option>
            <option class=optionText  value=\"hnd\">Hands</option>
            <option class=optionText  value=\"chk\">Checking</option>
            <option class=optionText  value=\"def\">Defense</option>
            <option class=optionText  value=\"faceoff\">Faceoffs</option>
        </select>
        <input type=hidden name=\"l\" value=".$_GET[l].">
        <input type=hidden name=\"t\" value=".$_GET[t].">
        <input type=hidden name=\"orderType\" value=".$_GET[orderType].">
        </form>";
}

function loadOrderTypeButton()
{
  echo "<form name=\"input\" action=\"colview.php\" method=\"get\">
        <select onchange=\"this.form.submit()\" class=optionText3 name=\"orderType\" id=\"orderType\">
            <option class=optionText  value=\"DESC\">DESC</option>
            <option class=optionText  value=\"ASC\">ASC</option>
        </select>
        <input type=hidden name=\"l\" value=".$_GET[l].">
        <input type=hidden name=\"t\" value=".$_GET[t].">
        <input type=hidden name=\"order1\" value=".$_GET[orderSel].">
        </form>";
}

function setLoadOrder()
{
  echo "<script>    
        var el = jQuery('select#orderSel option[value=\"".$_GET[orderSel]."\"]');
        var el = jQuery('select#orderSel option').filter(function(){return jQuery(this).text()==\"".$_GET[orderSel]."\"});
        el.attr(\"selected\", \"selected\");
        var el = jQuery('select#orderSel option:selected');
        el.text();  

        var el = jQuery('select#orderType option[value=\"".$_GET[orderType]."\"]');
        var el = jQuery('select#orderType option').filter(function(){return jQuery(this).text()==\"".$_GET[orderType]."\"});
        el.attr(\"selected\", \"selected\");
        var el = jQuery('select#orderType option:selected');
        el.text();
       </script>";
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are filtering the options based on its display text not its value, this works for `orderType` because its text and values are the same but not so for `orderSel`.

Use the value instead.

```
jQuery('#orderSel option').filter(function(){return jQuery(this).val()==\"".$_GET[orderSel]."\"});
```

If you want to set selected option you can just pass the option's value to the select's value

```
jQuery('#orderSel').val(optionValue);
```